# How to hide mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql

How to hide MySQL stored procedure: 
Like with encryption is available in SQL Server Store procedure. I try to hide stored procedure to outside users

Comment: "Like with encryption" ? - you mean hide its contents or hide its existence?

Comment: how are you going to expose a proc to users :) , as all I know is that you can pass the proc name and args to end users , nothing more is needed/required

Comment: How can you ask such a question with a straight face? Hide stored procedure from users? How do they see it? What do you achieve by "hiding" it? What does it do? Why do you use same user account that has access to stored procedure in the first place to allow users to connect to mysql? There is 0 knowledge demonstrated, you got my downvote.

Comment: You can only deny acces to others

Answer (score 3):

As documented under [`SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/show-create-procedure.html):

> This statement is a MySQL extension. It returns the exact string that can be used to re-create the named stored procedure. A similar statement, [`SHOW CREATE FUNCTION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/show-create-function.html), displays information about stored functions (see [Section 13.7.5.10, “`SHOW CREATE FUNCTION` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/show-create-function.html)”).
>
> Both statements require that you be the owner of the routine or have [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select.html) access to the `mysql.proc` table. If you do not have privileges for the routine itself, the value displayed for the `Create Procedure` or `Create Function` field will be `NULL`.

Therfore, to prevent users from viewing the body of a stored procedure, ensure that:

- they are not the owner of the sproc; and
- they do not have access to the `mysql.proc` table.

You can read more about [The MySQL Access Privilege System](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/privilege-system.html).